# Spring-integration File reading and convert to String

Tags: spring-integration

I am very new in Spring-integration , can any one help me plz,

Q-How to read a text file from "D:/file/" , show that content in a string variable and write in "D:/fileout/" directory.

using spring-integration tag base approach.
plz any one post the code and step by step process to compile.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

See the file sample (under basic) here

https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-integration-samples

Comment: ya I have imported that sample but , when I am running .I am not getting the required output

Comment: Turn on debug logging and you'll see what's happening.